# How quickly do I have to use my thawed pizza dough?

Tags: dough, pizza

I have never used frozen pizza dough before so I didn't know how long it would take for it to thaw out. I plan on using it tonight for dinner (in about 7-8 hours) and I thought it would take much longer for the rock hard dough to thaw out. I have had it covered and sitting on the kitchen counter and it's almost completely thawed out!

So once it's thawed can I keep it in the fridge until I'm ready to use it?

Comment: thawed means unfrozen (melted).  de thawed would mean refrozen.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, you can keep it in the fridge until you're ready to use it, up to 4-5 hours I would think. It will be too cold to over-ferment. It's better to defrost it in the fridge to avoid it getting too warm.