# Frozen bread dough that has been thawed out in the refrigerator for five days

Tags: food-safety

Is it safe to use frozen bread dough that has been thawed in the refrigerator for five days?  It was on a metal tray and dough covered with wax paper to keep it from drying out.  It did rise already some.  Not using it to make a regular loaf of bread so not concerned about it rising as much.

Comment: See related question [about thawed pizza dough](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23769/1549)

Answer (score 3):

Safe, yes.  Some recipes call for intentionally keeping the dough in the fridge for at least several days.  However, keep in mind that the flavor may be altered.  The yeast makeup of the dough may change over time.  Generally the dough will become more sour the longer it sits.